# Commenting out proof environments in my article

Tags: comments

I need to comment out all of the proofs in my article and uncomment it whenever I want; they are within this environment:

```
\begin{proof}
    contents
\end{proof}
```

I am wondering how to do that using a simple code.

Comment: Maybe the `comment` package helps. https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment --- @Mico already posted an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to retain the ability to show some proof environments selectively. If this is correct, I suggest you rename all `proof` environments (say) `commentproof`, load the [comment](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment) package in the preamble, and provide the instruction `\excludecomment{commentproof}` in the preamble. That way, the contents of the `commntproof` environments won't be shown. You can select which proofs to show by renaming them back to `proof`.

If *none* of the `proof` environments ever need be shown, a simpler procedure is available: Just load the `comment` package and provide the directive `\excludecomment{proof}`.

Comment: I am using `\includecomment{proof}`, but it just hide the _proof_ word at the beginning of the proofs, not the whole proofs.

Comment: @SaraWinslet - My apologies -- I should have written `\excludecomment{commentproof}` and `\excludecomment{proof}`, respectively. I will edit my answer to make the necessary corrections.